# how to loop through a database, show one entry and hide the rest

Tags: javascript, php

First off, I have php and mysql setup, I have a DB named WPF, table named colors and each entry has an ID auto-incrementing 1-55 and a colorcode.

What I am trying to achieve is set a php script to connect to the db(I have no issues with that) and I want it to loop through and for each color, show that color, hide others that are not the same color.

so the results should look like this

(show Red, hide Blue, hide Green, hide Orange)
(hide Red, show Blue, hide Green, hide Orange)
(hide Red, hide Blue, show Green, hide Orange)
(hide Red, hide Blue, hide Green, show Orange)

ultimately I will turn it into javascript so I can display one div when a button is clicked. If I click the Red button, all other color divs disappear.

I got the javascript to work manaully but since i have php and a database, I firgured there was an easier way than to type out all 55 colors and show/hide functions for each, 55 times.

```
onclick="
   $(\'#42B4E6\').hide();
   $(\'#D2D6D9\').hide();
   $(\'#002B7A\').show();"
```

works for me the '\' are there because Im having php echo it out. anybody know how I can spit this out correctly in php? 
the first three buttons work here but I dont want to type this manually
    https://www.dudermang.com/cfaulk/wpf4

```
<?php
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail1"><input type="button" style="background:#002B7A" id="b002B7A" onclick="$(\'#42B4E6\').hide();$(\'#D2D6D9\').hide();$(\'#002B7A\').show();"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="#thumbnail2"><input type="button" style="background:#42B4E6"  onclick="$(\'#002B7A\').hide();$(\'#D2D6D9\').hide();$(\'#42B4E6\').show();"/> </div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail3"><input type="button" style="background:#D2D6D9" onclick="$(\'#002B7A\').hide();$(\'#42B4E6\').hide();$(\'#D2D6D9\').show();"/>  </div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail4"><input type="button"style="background:#A8A8AA"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail5"><input type="button"style="background:#F27EB2"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail6"><input type="button"style="background:black"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail7"><input type="button"style="background:#474747"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail8"><input type="button"style="background:#FE4812"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail9"><input type="button"style="background:#7C2230"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail10"><input type="button"style="background:#4089eb"/></div>';

echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail11"><input type="button"style="background:#54565B"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail12"><input type="button"style="background:#5C4A3B"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail13"><input type="button"style="background:#B2BC00"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail14"><input type="button"style="background:#EBBECB"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail15"><input type="button"style="background:#6241"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail16"><input type="button"style="background:#5E8AB4"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail17"><input type="button"style="background:#892034"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail18"><input type="button"style="background:#AA1054"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail19"><input type="button"style="background:#2D1B46"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail20"><input type="button"style="background:#3B5E75"/></div>';


echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail21"><input type="button"style="background:#CC092F"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail22"><input type="button"style="background:#18453B"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail23"><input type="button"style="background:#FFB300"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail24"><input type="button"style="background:#253355"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail25"><input type="button"style="background:#007E3A"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail26"><input type="button"style="background:#A59D87"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail27"><input type="button"style="background:#55BE47"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail28"><input type="button"style="background:#8CB4E8"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail29"><input type="button"style="background:#4E2029"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail30"><input type="button"style="background:#3A4C00"/></div>';

echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail31"><input type="button"style="background:#F3ECE6"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail32"><input type="button"style="background:#A3D869"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail33"><input type="button"style="background:#FF1CAC"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail34"><input type="button"style="background:#E9E73F"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail35"><input type="button"style="background:#D5C4A1"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail36"><input type="button"style="background:#FF9C71"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail37"><input type="button"style="background:#38B8FF"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail38"><input type="button"style="background:#502D7F"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail39"><input type="button"style="background:#FF585E"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail40"><input type="button"style="background:#006F44"/></div>';

echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail41"><input type="button"style="background:#D00063"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail42"><input type="button"style="background:#7566A0"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail43"><input type="button"style="background:#385E9D"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail44"><input type="button"style="background:#1D4F91"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail45"><input type="button"style="background:#948771"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail46"><input type="button"style="background:#E8FF6B"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail47"><input type="button"style="background:#FF6C3B"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail48"><input type="button"style="background:#89A386"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail49"><input type="button"style="background:#47C7C7"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail50"><input type="button"style="background:#D4D4E0"/></div>';

echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail51"><input type="button"style="background:#FF7900"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail52"><input type="button"style="background:#A7192D"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail53"><input type="button"style="background:#FFFFFF"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail54"><input type="button"style="background:#5E2751"/></div>';
echo'<div class="trigger_color" id="thumbnail55"><input     type="button"style="background:#FFE000"/></div>';

?></div>
<div align="center">
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` that you try to hide or show is not valid:
Your id are, and it's in the `div` not in the `input`:

```
thumbnail1
thumbnail2
```

not:

```
#42B4E6
#D2D6D9
```

If you want to hide the block according to its colors, create a `data-color` attribute for example, and add the color to that created data, and in your code:

```
$('div').find(input[data-color='#42B4E6']).hide();
```